# Download or install failed

Tags: ubuntu-touch, 15.04

After updating my Nexus 4 to Ubuntu 15.04 (r2) two days ago I get an error when trying to install apps from the store

```
Download Error - Download or install failed. Please try again
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Open up the terminal and type "sudo apt-get update" and tell use whether there are any broken repositories showing.

Comment: close voters: 15.04 is not EOL for Ubuntu Touch

Comment: @Zanna I think it's EOL now. So VTC again...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix OK but wrong close reason. Not EOL when asked, so no-repro (abandoned and unanswerable), not EOL...